# Python shutils won't copy files

Tags: python, file, shutil

I am writing a simple script that searches a folder for a list of PDFs. Upon finding a matching PDF, the script should copy the PDF to another folder. However, it will only copy them with no data. They read 0kb and do not open in Acrobat. This is on windows 10.

shutil.copy, shutil.copy2, and shutil.copyfile all give the same results. A list of PDFs with the right names but no data. If I hard code the file name to do just one, it works fine. I seriously can't pass python functions a concatenated string for the paths? That's garbage. The shutil docs say the copy function's paths should be strings.

```
id = ['1','2','3']
os.chdir("C:/msds/")
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    # split file's name from extension            
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    # find if file is in the list of ones to search for
    if file_name in id:
        s = os.path.join("C:/msds/", file)
        d = os.path.join("C:/msds/deluxe/", file)
        shutil.copy(s,d)
```

Sample output:

```
print(s)
print(d)

C:/msds/032-0200.pdf
C:/msds/deluxe/032-0200.pdf
C:/msds/032-0950.pdf
C:/msds/deluxe/032-0950.pdf
C:/msds/040-1300.pdf
C:/msds/deluxe/040-1300.pdf
C:/msds/052-0600.pdf
C:/msds/deluxe/052-0600.pdf
```

Hard-coding a path string worked previously, but now it doesn't for some reason. I am giving up. I can only conclude that Python is not suitable for windows file manipulation, and anyone having this problem in the future should use another language.

Comment: Is there any output?  Have you checked that your string concatenation produces the result you think it should?

Comment: PS.  functions don't know how the object (including strings) they receive are created; it doesn't know if you hard-coded it or concatenated something else together.

Comment: @dhs Paths are correct. I changed it to print them and they are fine. It writes them to the correct folder, just without data

Comment: Yeah, you are having some kind odd problem.  As a starter, try using os.path.join and os.path.basename instead of the custom handling you have there.  I don't work in Windows, so I don't know what might be your problem here.

Comment: Perhaps the source folder is attribute-read-only to python?

Comment: @ErikJohnson If I fill out the full path manually with a real file, it copies it perfectly though. It's just the string concatenation that it does not like, and that is the whole point of the script is to make those paths for the copy function. Using os.path.join to make the paths did not change it

Comment: and there are no duplicate slashes or other strangeness?

Comment: Nothing. All I have to do to make it work is hard code the file variable to a string of a specific filename. It even works to concatenate the two hard coded strings

Comment: @deflator Show us the hard-coded paths that work, and the output of `print( "C:/msds/"+file ); print( "C:/msds/deluxe/"+file)`.  Without that information all I can tell you is that `shutil.copy()` does work.

Comment: `glob("./[1-3].pdf"))` will also find the file directly

Comment: Have you tried using  `os.path.normpath` before copying? Technically your separators are wrong - on Windows correct separator is backslash, not slash.

Answer (score 0):

As Lukasz Rogalski commented, Windows uses backslashes not forwards slashes. It's much better to import os and use os.sep in a string concatenation. The following is from part of a script I wrote, that would look at two directories and copy any files that were newer into another folder.

```
import os

def GetFiles(dir):
    dict = {}
    for subdir, dirs, files in walk(dir):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + filename
            filelocal = filepath[len(dir):]
            modTime = getmtime(filepath)
            dict[filelocal] = (modTime, filepath)
    return dict
```